# How to get Meteor.users collection on a Meteor package?

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

I'm developing a test frameword where I want to **reset all collections** on each run.

I'm having problems doing this with `Meteor.users`, since it's undefined on the package environment.

Is there any workaround to clean the Meteor.users collection from **within a package**?

Comment: Does your package have a dependency on `accounts-base`?

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Please post it as a comment so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package load order and exported variables matter when it comes to symbol availability in packages.

In order to get a symbol **created** in a package, it has to be loaded prior to your package. This can be achieved by depending on it or on some other package that **depends** on it.

Examples of such symbols are methods added to the `Meteor` object, and this is what is happening in your case.

```js
api.use('some-package'); // some-package is the desired package or depends on it
```

In order to get a symbol that is *exported* by a package, you should either **directly depend on it**, or depend on a package that **implies** this package (or **explicitly exports the symbol** on its own as well).

```js
api.use('some-package'); // some-package exports the symbol directly or by implying
```

You can make this dependency **weak** if you don't want the package to be added to the bundle if your package is the only one that depends on it (i.e, there are no other packages that strongly depend on it, and the user did not add it as a top-level dependency).

```js
api.use(['some-package'], ['client', 'server'], {weak: true});
```

If you need to do something after all of the packages have loaded, you can do so with `Meteor.startup()`:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  //do stuff after all packages and code were loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put some 'reset logic' on users collection, 
`Meteor.users.allow({
remove:function() { 
resetLogic(); });`

please check http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow for the reference

Comment: I don't think that this is relevant to the question. The `allow` callbacks are fired upon data mutation requests, they don't trigger them. Can you elaborate?